# Create a specific json object from rest api response

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a scenario where i am uoloading a csv file in a datatable and on button click i am sending all the rows to a endpoint api where they will be processed one by one using async function .I am sending this below payload to a rest api which in a async function

```
var b = [

    {
        "LastName": "LastName02",
        "Email": "FN02.LN02@gmail.com",
        "MobilePhone": "9198842"
    },
    {
        "LastName": "LastName03",
        "Email": "FN03.LN03@gmail.com",
        "MobilePhone": "+91 9884299071"
    },
]
```

Once async function runs i get response like below

for the 1st record i get which one part is below

```
resp.detailErrors = [
    {
      "errorCode": 7002,
      "field": "communicationNumbers.number",
      "value": "98842",
      "message": "For country India, Mobile length must be exactly 10 numeric digits, cannot start with zero."
    },
    {
      "errorCode": 7002,
      "field": "primaryEmailId",
      "value": "FN02.LN02@gmail.com",
      "message": "Invalid Primary Email Address"
    },
    {
      "errorCode": 7002,
      "field": "primaryEmailId",
      "value": "FN02.LN02@gmail.com",
      "message": "Invalid Primary Email Address"
    }
  ]
```

and for 2nd record i get

```
[
    {
        "errorCode": 7002,
        "field": "primaryEmailId",
        "value": "FN03.LN03@gmail.com",
        "message": "Invalid Primary Email Address"
    },
    {
        "errorCode": 7002,
        "field": "primaryEmailId",
        "value": "FN03.LN03@gmail.com",
        "message": "Invalid Primary Email Address"
    }
]
```

As for the datatable keyField is Email , so i want to display the error in a row wise . To display the error row wise i need to have to store error details in a specific manner which looks like below

```
let errors = { rows: {}}

     errors.rows['FN02.LN02@gmail.com'] = {
                title: 'error',
                messages: ['invalid email', 'invalid phone'],
                fieldNames: ['Email', 'MobilePhone']
            };

            errors.rows['FN03.LN03@gmail.com'] = {
                title: 'error',
                messages: ['invalid email'],
                fieldNames: ['Email']
            };
```

The code which i am trying is below , but its not working

```js
let map = [];
let errors = { rows: {} }
var key = '';

var resp = {"detailedErrors":[{"errorCode":7002,"field":"contactEntity.communicationNumbers.number","value":"98842","message":"For country India, Mobile length must be exactly 10 numeric digits, cannot start with zero."},{"errorCode":7002,"field":"primaryEmailId","value":"FN02.LN02@gmail.com","message":"Invalid Primary Email Address"},{"errorCode":7002,"field":"primaryEmailId","value":"FN02.LN02@gmail.com","message":"Invalid Primary Email Address"}],"correlationIdentifier":"df3df8e876bce7357fcc84ccd36a76f1"}

 resp.detailedErrors.forEach(res=>{
    key = res.Email 
    if(res.value.includes('@')) {
       map.push({
         key:res.value,
         val:res.message
       });
    } else {
      console.log(res)
      if(key == undefined) {
      
        map.push({
         key:key,
         val:res.message
       });
      }
    }
  }) 
  console.log(map)
```

Comment: The key for the `errors.rows` object in your desired output seems to be the email address returned by the error describing JSON. How will you determine the email address if only a faulty phone number was reported in the JSON - and there is no mention of an email address?

Answer (score 0):

`key = res.Email` will always set `key` as `undefined`, because `Email` doesn't exist on `res` object from your example. Maybe you meant to use `res.value` instead?

Also you probably don't need that empty object in map, instead of `let map = [{}];` can do `let map = [];`

Answer (score 0):

To generate error details in a row-wise manner, you must iterate through each row of your original data and then check to see if there are any errors associated with that row. The ***KeyField*** can be used to identify each row in the original data and then match it with the error in the ***resp.detailErrors*** array.

Here is a sample of code that should produce the required result:

```js
let errors = { rows: {} };
const data = [
  {
    "LastName": "LastName02",
    "Email": "FN02.LN02@gmail.com",
    "MobilePhone": "9198842"
  },
  {
    "LastName": "LastName03",
    "Email": "FN03.LN03@gmail.com",
    "MobilePhone": "+91 9884299071"
  },
];

const resp = {
  "detailErrors": [
    {
      "errorCode": 7002,
      "field": "communicationNumbers.number",
      "value": "98842",
      "message": "For country India, Mobile length must be exactly 10 numeric digits, cannot start with zero."
    },
    {
      "errorCode": 7002,
      "field": "primaryEmailId",
      "value": "FN02.LN02@gmail.com",
      "message": "Invalid Primary Email Address"
    },
    {
      "errorCode": 7002,
      "field": "primaryEmailId",
      "value": "FN02.LN02@gmail.com",
      "message": "Invalid Primary Email Address"
    },
    {
      "errorCode": 7002,
      "field": "primaryEmailId",
      "value": "FN03.LN03@gmail.com",
      "message": "Invalid Primary Email Address"
    },
    {
      "errorCode": 7002,
      "field": "primaryEmailId",
      "value": "FN03.LN03@gmail.com",
      "message": "Invalid Primary Email Address"
    }
  ]
};

// first create an object that maps each row's keyField value to the row object
const dataMap = {};
for (const row of data) {
  dataMap[row.Email] = row;
}

// and then iterate over each error and add it to the corresponding row in the errors object
for (const error of resp.detailErrors) {
  const key = error.value;
  const row = dataMap[key];
  if (row) {
    if (!errors.rows[key]) {
      errors.rows[key] = {
        title: 'error',
        messages: [],
        fieldNames: []
      };
    }
    errors.rows[key].messages.push(error.message);
    errors.rows[key].fieldNames.push(error.field);
  }
}

console.log(errors);
```

output:

```
{
  "rows": {
    "FN02.LN02@gmail.com": {
      "title": "error",
      "messages": [
        "Invalid Primary Email Address",
        "Invalid Primary Email Address"
      ],
      "fieldNames": [
        "primaryEmailId",
        "primaryEmailId"
      ]
    },
    "FN03.LN03@gmail.com": {
      "title": "error",
      "messages": [
        "Invalid Primary Email Address",
        "Invalid Primary Email Address"
      ],
      "fieldNames": [
        "primaryEmailId",
        "primaryEmailId"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Khattak01.. for row which has "FN02.LN02@gmail.com" email, the communication number "98842" is also error one. to display the number also i need to add error message and fieldname under "FN02.LN02@gmail.com" row. Not sure how to manage it ..